# How to redirect a URL and then rewrite it to same url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

There is PHP file redirect to

```
header("location:./exchange?title=".$directionin. '_'. $directionto);
```

I want to re-write this URL localhost/moneyworld/exchange?title=BTC_PMUSD
to this localhost/moneyworld/BTC_PMUSD
i have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /moneyworld/exchange?title=$1 [L]
```

and i put the .htaccess file in the root and it didn't work then i put it in moneyworld folder and also it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(based on your shown samples), In case you are looking to rewrite/redirect from `localhost/moneyworld/exchange?title=BTC_PMUSD` to `localhost/moneyworld/BTC_PMUSD` URL then try following

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(moneyworld)/exchange\?title=([^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [NE,QSD,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /moneyworld/exchange?title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @Amit Verma Hi i am thinking that if i want it without moneyworld folder like www.domain.com/exchange without /(moneyworld)/   Thanks

Comment: @MohamedNabil, Hi Nabil, you could open a new question for this along with your efforts and with clear requirements. Its not advised to edit or change requirements for old questions, cheers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65682014/how-to-redirect-a-url-and-then-rewrite-it-to-same-url-with-htaccess-but-from-the